# Slow boot time since upgrade to 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, lvm

After I upgraded to 16.04, the boot time has increased. 
The system stucks for about 80 sec with the message : 
`A start job is running for dev-mapper-sysvg\x2dlvhome.device"`

Here is some info :

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.257s (kernel) + 2min 3.377s (userspace) = 2min 8.635s

$ systemd-analyze blame
     10.868s vboxadd.service
      8.220s ModemManager.service
      7.230s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.476s accounts-daemon.service
      5.223s vboxadd-x11.service
      5.194s mdadm.service
      5.005s networking.service
      4.991s dev-sda1.device
      4.953s NetworkManager.service
      4.836s apport.service
      4.260s lightdm.service
      3.939s speech-dispatcher.service
      3.610s thermald.service
      3.575s virtualbox-guest-utils.service
      3.406s gpu-manager.service
      2.601s postfix.service
      2.425s rsyslog.service
      2.418s polkitd.service
      2.116s loadcpufreq.service
      2.098s lvm2-monitor.service
      2.036s ssh.service
      1.888s avahi-daemon.service
      1.758s grub-common.service
      1.486s colord.service
      1.379s systemd-logind.service
      1.352s irqbalance.service
      1.299s run-rpc_pipefs.mount
      1.266s systemd-journald.service
      1.069s systemd-udevd.service
      1.001s systemd-modules-load.service
       950ms brltty.service
       917ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       879ms ondemand.service
       855ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       761ms console-setup.service
       622ms virtualbox.service
       602ms dev-mqueue.mount
       601ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       567ms dev-hugepages.mount
       461ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       411ms systemd-sysctl.service
       328ms user@1001.service
       312ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       255ms upower.service
       253ms dns-clean.service
       246ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       220ms ntp.service
       217ms plymouth-read-write.service
```

and here is the chart: given by `systemd-analyze plot` 
[chart of boot time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohcZ6.jpg)

As we can see, some services initializing the hard drive are taking ages.
I have an lvm, here is the setup :

```
$ sudo lvs
  LV              VG    Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lvhome          sysvg -wi-ao---- 180,00g
  lvroot          sysvg owi-a-s---  20,00g
  lvswap          sysvg -wi-a-----   8,00g
  snap-2017-05-09 sysvg swi-a-s---  20,00g      lvroot 56,68

$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG    Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb7  sysvg lvm2 a--  234,55g 6,55g

$ sudo vgs
  VG    #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  sysvg   1   4   1 wz--n- 234,55g 6,55g
```

Edit 1 : I removed my hard drive with a lvm and startup time falls to ~30 sec :

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.299s (kernel) + 26.234s (userspace) = 31.534s

Systemd-analyze blame
      9.541s vboxadd.service
      6.516s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.321s networking.service
      5.366s dev-sda1.device
      5.318s NetworkManager.service
      4.937s ModemManager.service
      4.741s apport.service
      4.709s mdadm.service
      4.545s thermald.service
      4.316s vboxadd-x11.service
      4.025s speech-dispatcher.service
      3.307s accounts-daemon.service
      3.162s gpu-manager.service
      2.960s rsyslog.service
      2.775s virtualbox-guest-utils.service
```

I add back my hard drive with lvm, and, as suggested by @user535733, I removed `vboxadd.service`, `ModemManager.service`, `accounts-daemon.service`, `vboxadd-x11.service`, and startup time is still ~2min8.

Comment: Your *boot* time seems very fast. Your *login* time seems very slow. Start at the top of the login list and work down - do you really need to be running vboxadd at every login?

Comment: @user535733 thx for your feedback, I removed it and some more ans still have the issue, have a look at my edited section, I think it is related to lvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my self as I found the problem :

it was indeed lvm which was causing this slow startup time : I had a snapshot `snap-2017-05-09` which I had created before the upgrade in case something went wrong. 
Since the upgrade is disk consuming, the snapshot diverged a lot (10 Gb of data written), there are performance issue when scanning the lvm at startup with systemd ([here](https://blog.cuviper.com/2013/01/21/boot-time-versus-lvm-snapshots/%20link1), related to [linux-lvm mailling list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2007-May/msg00017.html)).

I solved my issue by deleting the snapshot and thus startup when down to ~35 sec.

Comment: AFAIK I have no snapshots and it takes 5min here :/